# Find database name from the stored procedure name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know the name of the database in which my stored procedure is there. I have used the below query to find it but it is not showing me the database name:-

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
'if exists(select 1 from [?].sys.objects where name=''sp_CreateEmail'')
select ''?'' as FoundInDb from [?].sys.objects where name=''sp_CreateEmail'''
```

It is only showing me the message:

> Command(s) completed successfully.

What I am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that is because the procedure `sp_CreateEmail` doesn't exist in your database. When I execute your code for the procedure `sp_MSrepl_startup` (which is in my master database), it shows one row.

Comment: Yes thats true. My bad! I selected the wrong server! Thanks working now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a procedure of that name.

As an aside, it's not a good idea to prefix stored procedures with SP_

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix